# Can the DOOM 3 demo be run on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, doom-3

I downloaded the DOOM 3 demo and tried running it on my WinVista box, but I got an error* and it won't run.

Is it compatible with Vista? If so, what do I need to do to get it to run?

**for those who want to know, it is an access violation reading location `0x000000`*

Comment: Yes it can. But not without modification. This requires manually editing files to account for changes between the demo and the working retail release. Even the 1.0 release works with Vista and up. It's just the demo that crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Doom 3 1.3.1 [patch notes](http://doom3.filefront.com/file/DOOM_3_Patch;76460), Doom 3 is Vista compatible. I'm assuming this implies that the original version had some compatibility issues.

According to various [threads](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/topic/26340154), the demo doesn't work properly in Vista, although the full game does.